# Não consigo realizar PUT e DELETE em Lista com relacionamento OneToMany Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse

Estou criando uma API via Spring Boot onde preciso fazer o PUT e DELETE de uma classe que será uma lista.

Criei uma classe "A" que vai receber a ligação da classe "B" que terá notação OneToMany, onde consegui com sucesso realizar o post e getAll desta classe B que é uma lista, essas duas classes estão com o crud no controller da clase "A".

Para realizar PUT, tentei de duas maneiras. A primeira é verificando se a classe-a existe, onde é retornado esta mensagem:
"The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!"

A segunda, não realizei busca pela classe "A", onde só inseri os parâmetros da classe "B" e quando faço isso, ele realiza um post para um outro local que não é o mesmo da URL que criei para o método GET e não consegui encontrar onde foi parar este post criado.

Em anexo, se encontram as duas formas que criei para realizar o put, eu não coloquei o delete, pois para fazer a busca do parâmetro "A" acredito que seja a mesma coisa.

Eu tentei desta forma que esta página explica, porém por eu não int para as variáveis ID e sim long, não consigo realizar o método delete:
https://www.sourcecodeexamples.net/2021/08/spring-boot-one-to-many-crud-example.html

Código com o parâmetro A informado na busca:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{classeAparametro}/classeb/{idClasseB}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Progressao atualizarClasseB(@PathVariable("classeAparametro") String classeAparametro, 
        @PathVariable("idClasseB") Long idClasseB, @Valid @RequestBody Classeb classeB) {
    if(!classeARepository.existsById(classeAparametro)) {
        throw new NaoEncontrado("Classe A não encontrado!");
    }
    return classeBRepository.findById(idClasseB).map( idClasseBSet -> {
        classeB.setData_ingresso(classeB.getData_ingresso());
        classeB.setModalidade_acesso(classeB.getModalidade_acesso());
        return classeBRepository.save(classeB);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new NaoEncontrado("Não existe classeB com este ID!"));     
}
```

Código sem o parâmetro citado na busca:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{classeAparametro}/classeb/{idClasseB}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Progressao atualizarClasseB(@PathVariable("classeAparametro") String classeAparametro, 
        @PathVariable("idClasseB") Long idClasseB, @Valid @RequestBody Classeb classeB) {
    if(!classeBRepository.existsById(idClasseB)) {
        throw new NaoEncontrado("Classe B não encontrado!");
    }
    return classeBRepository.findById(idClasseB).map( idClasseBSet -> {
        classeB.setData_ingresso(classeB.getData_ingresso());
        classeB.setModalidade_acesso(classeB.getModalidade_acesso());
        return classeBRepository.save(classeB);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new NaoEncontrado("Não existe classeB com este ID!"));     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas recomendo não utilizar o controller para criar regras de negocio, minha sugestão: se pretende excluir algo, crie um endpoint para isso e realize o procedimento no service.

Se tem algo na Classe A para excluir, o endpoint da Classe A é responsável por isso, o mesmo não deve excluir dados dos objetos Classe B e Classe C.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou refatorar